# Why does the expression `foldr (mappend . Sum) 1 [2]` type checks?

Tags: haskell

If I beta-reduce the following expression:

```hs
  foldr (mappend . Sum) 1 [2]
= (mappend . Sum) 2 (foldr (mappend . Sum) 1 [])
= (mappend . Sum) 2 1
= mappend (Sum 2) 1
...
```

Looking at the type of:

```hs
// mappend (<>) :: Monoid a => a -> a -> a
```

We can see the last line has a type error, because the constant `1` should belong to `Monoid` class (and it does not).

However, `ghci` doesn't complain.

Why does that expression type checks ?

Comment: It is crucial to know the type of your terms, the two numeric literals are *not the same type*: `foldr ((<>) . Sum) (1 :: Sum Int) [2 :: Int]`

Comment: Yes, of course. To me, both numeric literals had different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation for the Sum type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Sum) you will find this tell-tale instance:

```
Num a => Num (Sum a)
```

(which of course makes perfect sense that it should be there - not only is `Sum a` "morally the same type" as `a`, `Sum` is clearly designed to be used pretty much only with numeric types anyway).

Because numeric literals like `1` in Haskell can be of any type that's an instance of the `Num` class, there is no type error in `mappend (Sum 2) 1` because it is effectively translated into `mappend (Sum 2) (Sum 1)` automatically by the compiler. (Since in that `Num` instance for `Sum a`, `fromInteger 1` will be `Sum 1`.)

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**: `1` is interpreted as a `Sum a`, so the type of your foldr is:

```
foldr (mappend . Sum) 1 [2] :: Num a => Sum a
```

where `2` has type `a` and the `1` has type `Sum a`.

[**`Sum a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Sum) is an instance of `Num` if `a` is an instance of `Num`, indeed, [the source code says [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/Data.Semigroup.Internal.html#line-223):

```
newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a }
        deriving ( Eq       -- ^ @since 2.01
                 , Ord      -- ^ @since 2.01
                 , Read     -- ^ @since 2.01
                 , Show     -- ^ @since 2.01
                 , Bounded  -- ^ @since 2.01
                 , Generic  -- ^ @since 4.7.0.0
                 , Generic1 -- ^ @since 4.7.0.0
                 , Num      -- ^ @since 4.7.0.0
                 )
```

This thus means that if you write an integer literal, like `1`, it can be constructed as a `Sum a` for any `a` that is an instance of `Num`, so `1 :: Sum Integer` is `Sum 1`.

This thus means that the `1` in your `foldr` has type `Sum a`, and thus for example:

```
   mappend (Sum 2 :: Sum Integer) (1 :: Sum Integer)
-> Sum (2 + 1)
-> Sum 3
```

Comment: Thank you for the amazing answer, but there is something I do not understand. In my example, `1` is syntactic sugar for `fromInteger 1`, so that's the real reason why the expression `foldr (mappend . Sum) 1` type-checks. Is that right ?

Comment: @F.Zer: yes, that's right. For each int literal, it basically puts a `fromInteger` in front. But this is for a *literal*, not for an integer *expression*. So `1 + (2 :: Int)` will be an `Int`, not something as `fromIntegral (1+2 :: Int)`, etc.